# USB tethering BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way for my application to be "called" when the user enables USB tethering?

I've done the same for WiFi tethering simply using a broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.formichelli.vodafonetetheringfix.ApChangesReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But I can't find the right action for the USB tethering.

Answer (score 0):

manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ums_connected" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In .java file

```
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
            "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED")) {...}
    }
```